# Convert JSON string to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json object which contains some HTML. 
For example:

```
{
    "cat": "1",
    "catUrl": "this-is-a-url",
    "catSummary": "This is a summary with <a href=\"http://www.a.com\">a link</a>"
},
```

Notice catSummary has an href in it. But it doesn't get rendered as a link. Instead it just renders as regular text..

[image]

How do I make this work as a proper link?

**EDIT**
Just to clarify, I am using the VueJS framework, not jQuery.
A simple solution (that I completely missed..) is using the v-html directive.

Comment: Create a working snippet that demonstrate the issue you are facing.

Comment: `element.innerHTML = "This is a summary with <a href=\"http://www.a.com\">a link</a>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case all you want to do is populate another html element with the content in the catSummary field, use following:

```
$('#element_id').innerHTML = object_name.catSummary;
```

This will populate the element's object with the content in catSummary field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method after getting "catSummary" value from your json

```
$.parseHTML("This is a summary with <a href=\"http://www.a.com\">a link</a>")
```

Above method load your string as HTML and you can load into any element, See [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any library ? For example with jQuery you could simply do like this:

```
var data = {
    "cat": "1",
    "catUrl": "this-is-a-url",
    "catSummary": "This is a summary with <a href=\"http://www.a.com\">a link</a>"
};

$("body").html(data.catSummary);
```

and it will render as a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your json property "catSummary" and set into HTML controls

```
$("#" + elementId).innerHTML = "This is a summary with <a href=\"http://www.a.com\">a link</a>";
```